# local socket access denied in api23, working in api21

Tags: android, sockets, java-native-interface, native, android-permissions

I have an application and a service that are connected by local socket on the native level (C++/JNI). Both were built using target API level 21 and were working fine for years. Recently I have upgraded them to API level 23 and 
now I am constantly getting this error:

```
10-31 10:07:37.413 5760-5760/com.mycompany.myservice W/pool-151-thread: type=1400 audit(0.0:47942): avc: denied { connectto } for path=00494E554445565F4C4F43414C5F534F434B45545F53455256455200 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:untrusted_app_25:s0:c512,c768 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
10-31 10:17:44.373 4221-4221/com.mycompany.myapp W/pool-1-thread-1: type=1400 audit(0.0:72703): avc: denied { connectto } for path=00494E554445565F4C4F43414C5F534F434B45545F53455256455200 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:r:untrusted_app_25:s0:c512,c768 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
```

These lines are repeated constantly in logcat and there is nothing more.

I can see from this output that both the app and the service are considered as untrusted. I know that API 23 requests run time permissions, and both the service and the app request and get write, read, and internet runtime permissions.

My service manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.mycompany.myservice"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="2.03.0018.104"
    >

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" />

    <!-- Required for TCP IPC and for local socket --> 
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <!-- Copy data to SDcard + recording + temporary files -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application android:label="@string/app_name">

        <!-- Attacher hack -->
        <activity
            android:name="mynamespace.myservice$myserviceLauncher"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:excludeFromRecents="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
            <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED" android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
        </activity>

        <!-- Detacher hack -->
        <receiver android:name="mynamespace.myservice$Detacher">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_DETACHED" android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="mynamespace.myservice">
        </service>

    </application>
</manifest>
```

My app manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mycompany.myapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="2.01.00.06"
>

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="21"
    android:targetSdkVersion="23" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:logo="@drawable/icon"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Is there a way to **add both my service and my app to the trusted applications list**?

Or how else can I **make the local socket connection to work?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is due to further tightening of the platform's SE policies in order to remove potential attack vectors.  From the AOSP release info for Android 6.0:

> System Hardening. Hardening of the system via policies enforced by SELinux. This offers better isolation between users, IOCTL filtering, reduce threat of exposed services, further tightening of SELinux domains, and extremely limited /proc access.

The SE policy file for untrusted apps (the default for 3rd party app installs) explicitly disables access to UNIX domain sockets:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/sepolicy/+/android-6.0.1_r81/untrusted_app.te#141

The recommended practice for Android is not to use sockets for IPC, use binder for method like invocation.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to whitelist my app by asking the user? Otherwise I need to rewrite a huge chunk of my app and service. :-(

Comment: No, not that I know of for this case. Some of the runtime permissions will trigger the app to get placed into different security contexts for SE, but AFAIK there is no such thing for Unix domain sockets.

Comment: Bad news. I will wait a little more for somebody probably answering with some kind of hack or workaround and then I will accept your answer. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome, good luck!  Another option you could look at (though I don't find it as elegant as just using binder) would be to use an `Intent` to start the `Service` and send it a `Messenger` object.  The `Service` can then send a message to it and include its own `Messenger` object.  Now you can send messages between the two as if sending to a `Handler`.  That might be a little closer to what you are doing with the socket.  The biggest thing you need to remember is when using binder or `Messenger` or `Intent` (the latter ride on top of binder) is your data must be `Parcelable`.

Comment: One more clarification: both in service and in app the actual use of sockets was on the native libraries /JNI level. Does it matter?

Comment: Nope, not at all. The security context of an app isn't tied to the runtime (Java/Kotlin) sandbox. It's for the app process(es).

Comment: Larry, the last question, hopefully you don't mind. I was told by somebody to  use UDP sockets and to bind to a file instead of port number. Does this sound reasonable to you?

Comment: That's not really a valid thing.  UDP and TCP are built on the network IP stack, requiring a network port binding.  Named sockets, bound to a file name, are unix domain sockets; or, they could be thinking of named pipes (`man 7 fifo`). In any case, sockets/files aren't the most efficient way of exchanging data and also don't handle Android's memory/process killing model so they can leak resources if you are not very careful. Binder is the recommended way of doing IPC for almost all cases in Android.